# How to add elements to an array by verifying that user's input are only numbers?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to add 3 elements to my array, but I want to make sure that user's input are ONLY numbers. So far I have my for loop that allows the user to enter 3 numbers and if the user enters an input that IS NOT A NUMBER I subtract 1 so I still make sure I only get 3 numbers. After running my code I get an Exception error (Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException). Please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance!

```
     int[] arr = new int[3];

     for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
            try
            {
               System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
               arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                i--;
               System.out.println("Please enter a valid number");
               arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
```

Comment: what was your inputs..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the next token isn't an `int`, calling `scan.nextInt()` will not consume the token. Instead, you should consume the non-`int` with a call to `scan.next()` (in the `catch` block). Something like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    try {
        System.out.printf("Please enter a number for arr[%d]:%n", i);
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        i--;
        System.out.printf("%s is not a number.%n", scan.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the way you use arr[%d] to target each number. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Use [hasNextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) to check if next token is int or not. 
See following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    try {
        System.out.printf("Please enter a number: ");
        if(scan.hasNextInt()){
            arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }else{
           i--;
           System.out.println(scan.next() + " is not a number.", );
         }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```